# assigning own DOM structure to window.document is not updating dom

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, dom, reactjs

I am working on idea how react came into existence so i came across virtual dom concept after completing critical rendering path concepts, Virtual Dom as far i know one library lets say react will clone a DOM using

```
document.getElementById("myid").style.backgroundColor="green";
var t=document.cloneNode(true);
```

which copies whole dom and corresponding changes on dom will updated on t like..

```
t.getElementById("myid").style.backgroundColor="yellow";
t.getElementById("myid").innerHTML="<div>hi</div>";
```

Then my library will do some diff algorithm and add the changes the DOM
but here i got into some problem like

```
document=t;//it is assigning but background is still green
documnet.importNode(t);//even this is not working
```

what to do if i want to update document?
Please let me know am i in a right way to the virtual dom concept understanding?

Comment: vdom is not a dom, but your clone is. there's not much advantage to using a whole 'nother dom, even if it is off-document. once you have a list of primitive dom mods, you use the real dom's remove(), appendChild(), node.data=, etc to reconcile the changes with the live dom.

Comment: i didnt get that point "once you have a list of primitive dom mods you use doms remove,appendchild()" but i am not doing that. whenever i want to change i will change in clone and finally i will assign to dom so instead of 5 reflows and repaints it will be a single task for browser to relayout and paint.please tell me if i am wrong.and vdom is not dom then how it happens?